# Does the functional is continuous with respect to seminorm topology?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider family of seminorms:

$$p_n(f) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|f(\frac{k}{n})|$$

on $R[x]$ (polynomials with real coefficients)

I want to check two things - whether $p_n$ separate points and if functional

$$\varphi(f) = \int_0^1f(x) dx$$

is continuous with respect to this family of seminorms topology

**My work so far**

Firstly let's check if seminorm $p_n$ separate points i.e.

$$p_n(f) = 0 \Rightarrow f \equiv 0$$

$$p_n(f) = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n |f(\frac k n)| = 0 \Rightarrow \forall_{k = 1,2,3,...,n}:f(\frac k n) = 0$$

The only good example which would show that I can choose non zero function which zeroes $p_n(f)$ is:

$$f(x) = a(x-1)(x - \frac 1 2)(x - \frac 1 3)...(x - \frac 1 n)$$

but it depends on $n$ so its unacceptable example. By this fact we have that this seminorm has to separate points.

To check whether functional $\varphi$ is continuous with respect to family seminorm topology we have to check, whether there exists some finite set $F \subset \mathbb{N}$ and constant $C > 0$ for which
$$|\varphi(x)| \le C \sum_{n \in F}p_n(x)$$

$$|\int_0^1 f(x) dx| \le \frac{C}{n} \sum_{n \in F}p_n(x)$$

**Questions**

And here I have two questions:

> Does my argument that this seminorm does not separate points make
> sense to you? I think it's no so formal but I couldn't fin any better.

I could find find any good counterexample of the second problem. I know that there is inequality

$\sum_{i=1}^N f(i) \ge \int_0^N f(x)\,dx$ when function is increasing, however we are dealing with much more general problem.

> Could you please give me a hand with solving the second problem?
> (existence of $F$ and constant $C$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For the first point, the question is probably to show that *the family* of semi-norms $(p_n)$ separates points.

While you correctly showed that any one $p_n$ does not, the family as a whole does separate points. Indeed, if $f \in R[x]$ and $p_n(f) = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$, then $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $[0,1]$ and therefore $f=0$.

2. For the second point, the functional $\varphi$ is actually not continuous. To show this, notice that for any fixed set $F\subset \mathbb N^*$, the set $E = \{ k/n : n\in F, 1 \leq k \leq n\}$ is finite. Therefore, there is a non-zero polynomial $f$ with $f(x) = 0$ for every $x\in E$. Then, $\varphi(f^2) >0$ while :
   $$\sum_{n\in F}p_n(f^2) = 0$$